# How to manage whitespaces in a way that when an integer is inputted a pyramid shape forms (language: C)?

Tags: c

I am trying to get an output:[desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0nwR.png)

But i get this: [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5TR9.png)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

not really too sure how to solve.

Comment: You don't have any spaces in your `printf` strings. Why were you expecting your program to print spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = n; j > i; j--) {
            printf(" ");
        }        
        for (j = 1; j <= i*2-1; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int n, i, j,k;

printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 2*i-1; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    
     printf("\n");
    
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should start your loop control variables at 0 rather than 1. It’s going to hurt you sooner rather than later once you start working with pointers.

Comment: It is irrelevant to the current question@SafetyFast. Try not to drag imaginary situations into the current situation. Starting loop control variables at 0 or 1 or any other number depends on the memory location pointed by the pointers that we have to access specific to the question.